# Creating folder in Windows Event Viewer

Tags: c#, windows, events, viewer

I want to create a folder as "ABC" in Event Viewer under applications and service logs either manually or using C#

And want to log my files inside the folder "ABC". But I'm not able to create folder. I have no option for adding new folder in right click.

Can anyone help me to create folder manually or using C#. Even it can be created using command prompt or powershell.

Comment: You can create your own EventSource "ABC" but I dont think its possible under Application. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Niash.As far I searched we(administrator) can create a file ABC under applications and service logs (using c#) but not folder.